# PHP if condition in string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

In my Laravel project I try to add if conditions, everything works but when I try to check `if(true == true)` as a string it fails.

This is the string: `true && true && true && true`

Also if I tried: `true == false && true == false && true == true && true == true`

```
if($this->checkConditions($c_operator, $c_value, $c_value_given)) {
    $status = 'true';
} else {
    $status = 'false';
}

if(empty($run[$run_id]['query'])) {
    $run[$run_id]['query'] = ''.$status.' '.$rule->connection;
} else {
    $run[$run_id]['query'] .= ' '.$status.' '.$rule->connection;
}
```

The final response function

```
if($r['query']) {
    dump($r['query']);
} else {
    dump('error - '.$r['query']);
}
```

It will always dump `dump($r['query']);`

I also tried the `eval()` function, but that didn't work.

Maybe someone know if this is possible.

Comment: ... what? Could you please show us the actual code instead of your pseudo code?

Comment: Please provide more specific information about this problem.

Comment: What the.. are you trying to do? You check if the `bool true` is `bool false`, 2 times. Same with `bool true` is `bool true`

Comment: And what does `$r['query']` contain?

Comment: Use strict comparison  `===` when dealing with strings.

Comment: `if($string)` does not evaluate the contents of the string - it merely checks if the string is not empty.

Answer (score 4):

You can't evaluate a string as php like that. There's the `eval()` function (docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) but I must stress that this is usually an absolutely terrible idea.

A non-empty string in php evaluates to true. That's why your code always dumps the string even if it appears to contain boolean logic.

Edit: Heed this quoted quote from the comments of those docs:

> If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
>   wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Comment: Is it possible to makes this: `if($array['value1'] && $array['value2'] || $array['value3'])` if the data is in an array?

And is it's possible to add `&&` and `||` in a variable so the if condition is variable?

Comment: Should be, yes. I haven't tried it since I think it's a really bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you doing if with string like this:

```
if($string)
{
   //...do something
}
else
{
  //... do other thing
}
```

and if string is not empty and not equal to `"0"` or `"null"` it will always go to `true` part of `if..else` construction.